# keyCode displaying incorrect code value in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keycode

I'm working on capturing keys pressed to use with an API for fuzzy search results.

Anyways I'm using this code to capture keypresses in my Markup and Directive Controller:

```
<input type="text"
       placeholder="Search"
       ng-click="searchPop($event)"
       ng-keypress="typingMainSearch($event)">
```

---

```
vs.typingMainSearch = function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    vs.searchPopoverDisplay = true;
};
```

However when I type `a` I get `97`, when I type `b` I get `98`.

---

**Those are incorrect values when I compare them to any place I look online.**

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

[Is it possible to listen for arrow keyspress using ng-keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464579/is-it-possible-to-listen-for-arrow-keyspress-using-ng-keypress)

http://jsfiddle.net/YKeye/

Why is this the case? **a** is suppose to be **65** and **b** is suppose to be **66**:

```
 var key = {
      'a': 65,
      'b': 66,
      'c': 67,
      'd': 68,
      'e': 69,
      'f': 70,
      'g': 71,
      'h': 72,
      'i': 73,
      'j': 74,
      'k': 75,
      'l': 76,
      'm': 77,
      'n': 78,
      'o': 79,
      'p': 80,
      'q': 81,
      'r': 82,
      's': 83,
      't': 84,
      'u': 85,
      'v': 86,
      'w': 87,
      'x': 88,
      'y': 89,
      'z': 90
  }
```

Comment: small point , not relevant to problem but is confusing calling `event` object `key` in the handler. If you have jQuery included try `key.which` as comparison

Comment: check your CAPS LOCK

Comment: OH, ok so I turned CAPS LOCK on and now it's giving me the correct values :( hmmmmm how do you guys solve for this? People aren't typing full caps

Comment: Lol, I actually only needed to use `ng-model` instead of having to rely on this array / object `<input type="text" ng-model="searchInput"` Then whenever I hit the `keyUp` event, I just check that model lol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `ng-keyup` instead, this will work for you:

```
<input type="text"
       placeholder="Search"
       ng-click="searchPop($event)"
       ng-keyup="typingMainSearch($event)">
```

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) the `keyCode` property of keypress is deprecated.

Also - this is why you saw 97 when clicking 'a' for instance (taken from the Mozilla link):

> The Unicode reference number of the key;

You can find the unicode numbering table [here.](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec)